# dynamically reshape array size to avoid ValueError: cannot reshape array of size error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate softmax like the following:

```
def softmax_og(x):
     e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
     return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=-1) # only difference
```

At first I got `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,176,768) (1,176)`

After researched I found out this is because I was breaking the broadcast rules and should reshape to fix it.

I reshape ex_sum to `(1, 176, 768)` but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 176 into shape (1,176,768)
```

If I reshape to `reshape(1, 176, -1)` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 204 into shape (1,176,newaxis)
```

Even if I go by GCD between 204 and 176 where the reshape for both e_x and e_x.sum is `(1, 4, -1)` I get the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,4,33792) (1,4,44)
```

Is there a way to dynamically reshape the array so it always fits according to the size?

Am I missing something? Could this be a side effect of another problem?

Comment: `e_x / e_x.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)`

Comment: `reshape` can't change the total number of elements in the array.  That is, the product of the dimensions has to remain the same.  That's an even more fundamental rule than the broadcasting ones.

Comment: Some how you changed the array to having a (204) dimemnsion, as opposed to the (176).  `size 204 into shape (1,176,newaxis)`.  That (1, 176, -1) should work if it still had the 176 dimension.  `e_x.sum(axis=-1).[:,:,None]` should also work.  One way or other you want to divide (1,176,768) (1,176, 1) shapes.  That trailing `1` can be expanded to match `768`